# on_message discord py

Tags: python, discord.py, асинхронность, discord-api

В моем боте Discord есть 2 события on_message(), первое цензурирует сообщения, другое принимает DM, однако после добавления второго перестало работать первое

Вот код 1-го:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        for word in filtered_words:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                author = message.author
                dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
                await message.delete()
                chid = bot.get_channel(937207414623703080)
                await chid.send('User: "' + str(author) + '" | Act: Restricted word | Date/Time: ' + str(dt_now) + '\nUsed word: "' + word + '" | ' + 'In message: "' + message.content + '" ' + '| In channel: "' + message.channel.name + '"')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Код 2-го:

```
@bot.event

async def on_message(message):
    chid = bot.get_channel(939064043740729364)
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        if str(message.channel.type) == 'private':
            await chid.send('User: "' + str(message.author) + '" | Act: DMMessage | Wrote: "' + message.content + '" | Date/time: ' + str(dt_now))
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Пытался ставить те же await bot.process_commands(message) в разных местах и т.п. Дело заключается именно во втором событии, т.к. если закомментить его, то 1-е начинает работать.

Ломаю над этим голову 3-й день, не знаю что делать, прошу помощи. **В гугле нигде не нашел.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик событий `on_message()` может быть только один, поэтому работает только последний, так как заменяет собой предыдущие.

Чтобы решить проблему, просто объедините логику обработчика в одну функцию.

Например через проверку типа канала, из которого пришло сообщение:

```py
if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
    # действия обработчика принимающего DM
```